# React native gesture handler overwrites on android but not on ios

Tags: react-native

I was wondering why my react native if i wrap scrollview with gesture detector, I'm unable to scroll on android but able to scroll on ios. I was wondering how I can make my scrollview work on android.

Thanks!

```
const gest = Gesture.Pan().onUpdate((e) => {...})

return(
 <GestureDetector gesture={roomGestureTV}>
 <ScrollView ... />
</GestureDetector>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Snack that shows how to wrap a ScrollView with a PanGesture ([Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@jhauth-findus/scrollandpangesture) or below for future reference). I have tested the code on a Galaxy S9 (Android) and iPhone 13 (Real and Emulator).

Some notes (See the snack first!):

- The behaviour for android and IOS gestures differs, because they (react-native-gesture-handler) had to implement a custom solution on Android but not on IOS. On Android the pan gesture cancels the ScrollView gesture, but on IOS the ScrollView cancels the PanGesture. In both cases PanGesture and Scroll gesture do not work simultanously out of the box.
- Use createNativeWrapper instead of the ScrollView from gesture handler. While the ScrollView from gesture handler will work, other components that build on ScrollView will not (e.g. FlatLists). In order to use a FlatList instead of a ScrollView, exchange the ScrollView with a FlatList in createNativeWrapper
- createNativeWrapper is no longer activly supported by the libary ([Source](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/api/create-native-wrapper)). However, the [new](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/gestures/native-gesture)/[old](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/api/nativeview-gh) Native Gesture Component is not working for this use case (at least for me). This might be a bug and might be fixed in newer versions.
- Note that simultaneousHandlers for the ScrollView is not limited to one gesture but can accept multiple gestures. E.g. it is possible to have a pan and pinch gesture while scrolling.

##### Reference Code

```js
    import React, { useRef } from 'react';
    import { Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
    import Animated, {
      useDerivedValue,
      useSharedValue,
      useWorkletCallback,
    } from 'react-native-reanimated';
    import {
      createNativeWrapper,
      GestureHandlerRootView,
      Gesture,
      GestureDetector,
    } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import ReText from './components/ReText';

    /**
     * Gesture states 
     * (see https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/under-the-hood/states-events)
     */
    const STATES = {
      0: 'UNDETERMINED',
      1: 'FAILED',
      2: 'BEGAN',
      3: 'CANCELLED',
      4: 'ACTIVE',
      5: 'END',
    };

    const CustomScrollComponent = createNativeWrapper(ScrollView)

    export default function App() {
      const panRef = useRef(null);
      const scrollRef = useRef(null);

      // Log values
      const touchPosition = useSharedValue({ x: null, y: null });
      const touchPositionX = useDerivedValue(() => {
        return `x: ${touchPosition.value.x}`;
      });
      const touchPositionY = useDerivedValue(() => {
        return `y: ${touchPosition.value.y}`;
      });

      const state = useSharedValue([STATES[0], 'null', 'null']);
      const stateString = useDerivedValue(() => {
        return `${state.value[0]}\n${state.value[1]}\n${state.value[2]}`;
      });

      const appendState = useWorkletCallback((arr, value) => {
        return [value].concat(arr.slice(0, 2));
      }, []);

      const panGesture = Gesture.Pan()
        .onBegin((e) => {
          state.value = appendState(state.value, STATES[e.state]);
        })
        .onStart((e) => {
          state.value = appendState(state.value, STATES[e.state]);
        })
        .onUpdate((e) => {
          if (state.value[0] !== STATES[e.state]) {
            state.value = appendState(state.value, STATES[e.state]);
          }
          touchPosition.value = { x: e.absoluteX, y: e.absoluteY };
        })
        .onEnd((e) => {
          state.value = appendState(state.value, STATES[e.state]);
        })
        .onFinalize((e) => {
          state.value = appendState(state.value, STATES[e.state]);
          touchPosition.value = { x: null, y: null };
        })
        .simultaneousWithExternalGesture(scrollRef)
        .withRef(panRef);

      return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {/** Logger */}
            <View style={{ padding: 16, height: 180, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
              <ReText text={touchPositionX} />
              <ReText text={touchPositionY} />
              <Text>Gesture States (New -> Old):</Text>
              <ReText text={stateString} />
            </View>
            {/** ScrollView with pan gesture */}
            <GestureDetector gesture={panGesture}>
              <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <CustomScrollComponent
                  disallowInterruption={false}
                  scrollEnabled={true}
                  ref={scrollRef}
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                  simultaneousHandlers={panRef}>
                  <Text>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
                    diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
                    justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
                    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
                    dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
                    sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
                    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                    est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                    est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
                    rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                  </Text>
                </CustomScrollComponent>
              </Animated.View>
            </GestureDetector>
          </View>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
      );
    }
```